# is Treemap inside ConcurrentHashMap thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, treemap, concurrenthashmap

I have a case of nested maps as follows:

```
private final static Map<String, TreeMap<Long,String>> outerConcurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I know that `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe, but I want to know about the `TreeMap`s this CHM holding, are they also thread safe inside CHM ?

The operations I am doing are:

1. If specific key is not found --> create new TreeMap and put against key.
2. If key is found then get the TreeMap, and update it.
3. Retrieve TreeMap from CHM using `get(K)`.
4. Retreive data from TreeMap using `tailMap(K,boolean)` method.
5. `clear()` the CHM.

I want a thread-safe structure in this scenario. Is the above implementation thread-safe or not? If not then please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've done `TreeMap<?, ?> tm = chm.get(key);` you are not in thread safe territory any longer. In particular, if another thread updates the treemap (through the CHM or not) you may or may not see the change. Worse, the copy of the map that you have in `tm` may be corrupted...

One option would be to use a thread safe map, such as a ConcurrentSkipListMap.

Comment: But you will have to protect the copying operation somehow…

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no.

If your map is a ConcurrentHashMap, then all operations that affect **the state of your hashmap** are thread-safe. That does **not at all** mean that objects stored in that map become thread-safe.

How would that work; you create any kind of object, and by adding it to such a map, the object itself becomes thread-safe? And when you remove that object from the map, the "thread-unsafety" is restored?!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing all of this in multiple threads, no, it's not thread-safe.

Ignore the fact that you've *accessed* the `TreeMap` via a `ConcurrentHashMap` - you end up with multiple threads accessing the `TreeMap` at the same time, including one or more of them writing to the map. That's not safe, because `TreeMap` isn't thread-safe for that situation:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: When I am always accessing the TreeMap through ConcurrentHashMap will I still end up with multiple threads accessing it at same time...

Comment: thread-safety of CHM guarantees ACIDity of key-value associations, not of key or value objects themselves.

Comment: @tm.sauron: Yes, why wouldn't you?

Comment: Yep got it ..Thanks .. Its what I do with the objects retrieved that matters.

Answer (score 2):

**Some your scenarios are thread-safe, some are not:**

**1.** Yes this is thread safe though other threads cannot see newly created TreeMap until you put it to CHM. But this should be implemented carefully to avoid race conditions - you should make it sure that checking and insertion are performed atomically:

```
// create an empty treemap somewhere before
TreeMap<Long, String> emptyMap = new TreeMap<>();
...
// On access, use putIfAbsent method to make sure that if 2 threads  
// try to get same key without associated value sumultaneously,
// the same empty map is returned  
if (outerConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, emptyMap) == null) {
    emptyMap = new TreeMap<>();
};
map = outerConcurrentMap.get(key);
```

**2, 3, 4.** No, you first need to lock this TreeMap by explicit lock or using `synchronized`. `TreeMap` is not synchronized by itself.

**5.** Yes, this is operation is performed on CHM, so it is thread-safe.

If you need fully thread-safe sorted map, use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` instead. It is slower than `TreeMap` but its internal structure doesn't need to lock full collection during access thus making it effective in concurrent environment.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeMap itself should not be thread safe. Since only the methods of the `ConcurrentHashMap` are effected.

What you could do is following:

```
private final static Map<String, SortedMap <Long,String>> outerConcurrentMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SortedMap <Long,String> >();

static {
    // Just an example
    SortedMap map = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));
    outerConcurrentMap.put("...",map);
}
```